# What is Obi-Wan referring to when he says "five thousand"?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Early on in *Revenge of the Sith*, Obi-Wan and Anakin are flying a half-burned spaceship:

> Obi-Wan: **Five thousand**. Fire ships on the left and the right.
>
> Pilot: We'll take you in.
>
> (Pilot sprays water on spaceship)
>
> [image]
>
> OBI-WAN: Copy that.

What do the words *"five thousand"* relate to here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's a little bit of extra dialogue in the [script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html) that would suggest that he's reading off their temperature (in degrees?)

> **OBI-WAN:** Careful . . . we're **heating up-twelve thousand . . . thirteen
> thousand . . .**
>
> **ANAKIN:** What's our speed?
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Eight plus sixty-forty. Eight plus sixty-twenty. Eight plus
> sixty. **Temp ten thousand, nine thousand** . . . we're in the atmosphere
> . . .
>
> ANAKIN points to one of the controls. ARTOO beeps madly.
>
> **ANAKIN:** Grab that . . . Keep us level.
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Steady. Steady.
>
> **ANAKIN:** Easy, Artoo. Hang on, this may get a little rough. We lost our
> heat shields.
>
> **OBI-WAN:** **Five thousand. Three thousand . . . two thousand.** Fireships
> on the left and the right.

Comment: Another happy landing. Since the numbers are decreasing, I'd argue they're either altitude or distance from the landing strip. Temperature should rise upon entering the atmosphere sans heat shields, as Obi-Wan's first line suggests. The dialogue from the script doesn't quite match [what's going on in the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwEECZjnPEM), but close enough for government work.

Comment: I seriously hope they have a different measurement unit for temperature in the SW universe. 

Comment: @elemtilas - It rises as they're entering the atmosphere in an uncontrolled fashion. As Anakin takes control of the ship, the number lowers. It goes down further as they get deeper into the atmosphere and lower still once they're sprayed with fire foam. It seems very clear that it's temp that he's reading off in thousands ("*Temp ten thousand"*), not least because he's also reading off the speed ("*Eight plus sixty-forty*")

Comment: @Shreedhar - I thought about that. If it was Kelvin, that would actually be a quite reasonable figure compared to other re-entry craft that pre-date The Shuttle.

Comment: With 13.000 it doesn't really matter if Kelvin or Celsius, since your space ship is either gas or plasma either way

Comment: @Christian -This is, of course, a universe where heat shields are a thing. They go from orbit to ground in an insanely short amount of time, which would presumably result in super-heating. I'm not sure if the science adds up though, probably not.

Comment: @Valorum We have [heat shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_shield)

Comment: @CaptainMan - Those are physical shields, not forcefields.

Comment: @Valorum Very true, we don't have forcefields. I haven't seen the clip recently so can't recall if they show a forcefield for reentry. That said, we do have heat shielding that makes a cool pocket of air which is kind of like a forcefield. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry#Ablative

Comment: @Valorum Looking at the battle though, they don't seem to actually be in orbit, they look like they just hover at orbital altitude.

Comment: @Ryan_L - They were moving quite rapidly though. Whatever "Eight plus sixty-forty" is, it's not a sustainable speed for landing.

Comment: @Shreedhar: They use Celsius. https://aminoapps.com/c/star-wars/page/blog/learning-star-wars-in-depth-guide-to-measurements-used-in-sw/dKFb_u2gbxJpWG1nWmeX5QZjVgWnor#:~:text=In%20Star%20Wars%2C%20they%20mostly,Both%20are%20measured%20in%20degrees.